# Remove from ldap

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

Need help to remove specific owner from the ldap server using power shell script.

```
$obj.filter = "cn = group1"
$result = $obj.findall().properties
        
$result.owner
```

Getting all the owner of group1. Need to remove individual owner based on uid ?

Comment: You're not showing enough code to work with. For example, what is `$obj`? But I'm sure the answer can be found on Google if you search.

Comment: In $obj i have ldap connection . I didn't find anything .

Comment: Try checking `Set-ADGroup -ManagedBy ...`